# Launch image different sizes screens

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Hi i have file **"LaunchScreen.storybord"**

And in iPhone 5s 5 and 4s its look very different.

**How i can fix it?**

[image: iPhone 6 screen]

[image: iPhone 5s , 5 screen]

[image: iPhone 4s screen]

Comment: You can fix that by creating the *correct* constraints, not much we can do here without any shown constraints.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025261/how-to-set-a-launch-screen-image-in-xcode

Comment: im using with Autorisizeing

Comment: Try using `stackviews` with constraints.

Comment: i did it , its work :) thanks you