# How can I add splash image in xcode?

Tags: xcode

First, I will use static image for splash screen.

I have a quick questions about registering launch image.

I was trying to add images in launchImage file in Images.xcassets folder. However, I don't let user to rotate screen so I don't need landscape images. Do I have to add all of images in launchImage file to complete launch images?

Thanks.

Comment: No you don't. Just update the LaunchScreen.storyboard file with the image in portrait mode.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025261/how-to-set-a-launch-screen-image-in-xcode) might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends to use a Launch Screen that let you to have the page automatically adapted to the screen sizes of different devices and environments

[Apple documentation about Launch Screen](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)